# Trying to reflect changes in Redux State from CurrentUser on React DOM for CurrentUser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, redux, jwt, token

My app is a dashboard that allows the public to view certain items but not CRUD. If a user logs in, full CRUD is accessible. I'm using home spun JWT/Bcrypt auth in Rails backend and React/Redux for the frontend and state management. I'm wondering the best strategy to have the React DOM immediately reflect when a user login/logout and have certain items like create buttons appear/disappear based on login status. Right now, `this.props.currentUser` coming from the Redux store doesn't seem to help even though the Redux store has updated.

I'm using JSX ternary operators to display certain items based on currentUser state. I've tried `this.props.currentUser ? <button>Example</button> : null` or `this.props.currentUser !== null ? <button>Example</button> : null` and `this.props.currentUser.length !== 0 ? <button>example</button> : null`, none of which I get any consistency (might work for one compnonent but on page refresh no longer works, etc).

Here's an example component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container, Grid, Image } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import logo from "../../images/logo-2-dashboard";
import { clearCurrentUser } from "../actions/clearCurrentUserAction";

class Header extends Component {

  logout = () => {
    localStorage.clear();
    this.props.clearCurrentUser()
    this.props.history.push("/");
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <>
        <Container fluid>
          <Grid divided>
            <Grid.Row columns={2}>
              <Grid.Column>
                <Image
                  src={logo}
                  size="large"
                  style={{ margin: "3px", padding: "2px" }}
                ></Image>
              </Grid.Column>
              <Grid.Column>

                 // Here's the kitchen sink approach lol 

                {this.props.currentUser && this.props.currentUser === null ||
                this.props.currentUser && this.props.currentUser.length === 0 ? (
                  <Link
                    to={"/login"}
                    onClick={this.props.login}
                    style={{ marginLeft: "200px" }}
                  >
                    Login
                  </Link>
                ) : (
                  <Link
                    to={"/"}
                    onClick={this.logout}
                    style={{ marginLeft: "200px" }}
                  >
                    Logout
                  </Link>
                )}

                 // SAME HERE 

                {this.props.currentUser && this.props.currentUser !== null ||
                this.props.currentUser && this.props.currentUser.length !== 0 ? (
                  <div>Logged in as: {this.props.currentUser.username}</div>
                ) : null}
              </Grid.Column>
            </Grid.Row>
          </Grid>
        </Container>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        currentUser: state.currentUser.currentUser
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    clearCurrentUser: () => dispatch(clearCurrentUser())
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(Header));
```

Here is my Redux Action Thunk to set CurrentUser back to null on logout (I'm also clearing localHistory):

```
export const CLEAR_CURRENT_USER = 'CLEAR_CURRENT_USER'

export const clearCurrentUser = () => dispatch => {
     return dispatch({ type: 'CLEAR_CURRENT_USER', payload: null })
}
```

and the Reducer for currentUser:

```
const initialState = {
  currentUser: [],
};

export const currentUserReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_CURRENT_USER": 
            return { ...state, currentUser: action.payload }
        case "GET_CURRENT_USER":
            return { currentUser: action.payload }
        case "CLEAR_CURRENT_USER":
            return { currentUser: action.payload }
    default:
        return state;  
    }
};
```

Perhaphs this is the wrong approach altogether. I'm a junior working on my own at a company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are checking if currentUser is truthy but your initialstate is an array. your initialState for currentUser reducer should be null instead of an empty array.

```js
const initialState = {
  currentUser: null,
};

export const currentUserReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_CURRENT_USER": 
            return { ...state, currentUser: action.payload }
        case "GET_CURRENT_USER":
            return { currentUser: action.payload }
        case "CLEAR_CURRENT_USER":
            return { currentUser: action.payload }
    default:
        return state;  
    }
};
```